# How do I change model coefficients to compare a model in the literature?

Tags: r, stargazer

I'd like to compare the coefficients from my own replication of a statistical model in the literature with the coefficients in the literature. I thougth I could just duplicate my model, and then plug in the coefficients from the literature and print both. But I'm getting this error:

`Error in if (coef.var[i] == .global.coefficient.variables[j]) { : 
  argument is of length zero`

What is the easiest way to do this?

```
##fake data
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)
#My own model
model1<-lm(var1~var2, data=df)

#Duplicate my own model
model2<-model1
#Try to change the coefficients to match what appears in the literature
model2$coefficients<-c(5, 10)
#Try to report
library(stargazer)
stargazer(model1, model2,type="html")
```

Comment: When do you get the error - I don't have `stargazer` installed, but up until then your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2)

model1<-lm(var1~var2, data=df)

model2<-model1

model2$coefficients[[1]] <- 5
model2$coefficients[[2]] <- 10


library(stargazer)
stargazer(model1, model2,type="html")
```

Comment: Hmm..  So is the object model2$coefficients a list itself? Or a vector?

Comment: It is a named vector. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do. I'm just curious to know why this didn't work. `model2$coefficients<-c(5, 10)`

Comment: @spindoctor; it seems as if it need the names; so you can use `attributes(model2$coefficients)=attributes(model1$coefficients)` .. in fact just using `model2$coefficients[1:2] = c(5,10)` does the trick